# Not able to set initial values and onchange of input elelements in DataTable React Js

Tags: jquery, reactjs, input, setstate

I have a dataset coming down from Parent component to child component(DataTable). I am creating a datatable with the incoming data. I am able to create DataTable but I am facing 2 issues:

1. I am not able write inside the input elements of Datatable
2. I am not able to set initial values of input boxes according to the incoming data

My goal is I want to set some initial values(dynamic, based on data) of all the inputs and user should be able to edit the input values.

I am new to React and I am not able to understand the issue

Following is my code:

```
import react, {Component} from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class Datatable extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            value:""
        }

        this.generateHeader = this.generateHeader.bind(this);
        this.generateTableData = this.generateTableData.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event){
        console.log("change clicked");
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    generateHeader(){
        const columnHeader = ["Deposit name", "Amount"]
        let res=[];
        for(var i =0; i < columnHeader.length; i++){
            res.push(<th key={columnHeader[i]}>{columnHeader[i]}</th>)
        }
        return res;
    }

    generateTableData(){
        let tableData = this.props.snapshotData.data.deposits;
        let invenstments = tableData.Investment;
        let liquid = tableData.Liquid;
        let savings = tableData.Savings;
        let arr = $.merge(this.createRow(invenstments), this.createRow(liquid))
        let res = $.merge(arr, this.createRow(savings));
        return res;
    }

    createRow(data){
        let res=[];
        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            res.push(
                <tr>
                    <td key={data[i].name}>{data[i].deposit_name}</td>
                    <td key={data[i].id}><input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handlehange} /></td>
                </tr>
            )
        }
        return res;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-header">
                          <h3 className="card-title">DataTable with default features</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <table id="example1" className="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    {this.generateHeader()}
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                  {this.generateTableData()}
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                  <tr>
                                    {this.generateHeader()}
                                  </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The initial value that I want to set to input values is: data[i].amount in createRow(data) method.

The input json format is given below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "deposits": {
            "Investment": [
                {
                    "amount": 1000.0,
                    "deposit_name": "Test 12",
                    "id": 12
                },
                {
                    "amount": 1000.0,
                    "deposit_name": "Test 13",
                    "id": 13
                }          
            ],
            "Liquid": [
                {
                    "amount": 1000.0,
                    "deposit_name": "Test 3",
                    "id": 3
                }
            ],
            "Savings": [
                {
                    "amount": 1000.0,
                    "deposit_name": "Test 1",
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "amount": 1000.0,
                    "deposit_name": "Test 2",
                    "id": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "message": "success",
    "status": true
}
```

Comment: What's the shape of Investment / Liquid / Savings ? Do they have an uniqueId ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question

Comment: In generateTableData() you use the variable tableData.Liquid / tableData.Investment and tableData.Savings, what are the properties inside these object ?

Comment: I have editted my question to give the input json also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the details you shared in your code, I'll assume the `Datatable` component is being used in the following manner:

```
<Datatable
  snapshotData={{
    data: {
      deposits: {
        Investment: [{ amount: 0, deposit_name: "", id: "" }, ...],
        Liquid: [{ amount: 0, deposit_name: "", id: "" }, ...],
        Savings: [{ amount: 0, deposit_name: "", id: "" }, ...],
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

from there, without changing your code too much we need to make sure the initial state includes the correct data

we will move your logic from `generateTableData` to the construction phase

this will help us initiate the component with the correct data structure:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  let tableData = this.props.snapshotData.data.deposits;
  let invenstments = tableData.Investment;
  let liquid = tableData.Liquid;
  let savings = tableData.Savings;
  let merged = [].concat(invenstments).concat(liquid).concat(savings);
  let state = {
    items: {},
    ids: []
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
    state.items[merged[i].id] = merged[i];
    state.ids.push(merged[i].id);
  }

  this.state = state;

  this.generateHeader = this.generateHeader.bind(this);
  this.generateTableData = this.generateTableData.bind(this);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

from the logic above, we'll have a `this.state` that looks like:

```
this.state = {
  items: {
    12: {
     "amount": ...,
     "deposit_name": ...,
     "id": ...,
    },
    13: {...}
  },
  ids: [12, 13, 3]
}
```

this structure helps us to "lookup-and-update" the values in `this.state.items` and also iterate on these objects using `this.state.ids`

now on `handleChange`, we need to lookup the correct object and generate a new state for react:

```
handleChange(event) {
  let nextState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
  nextState.items[event.target.id].amount = event.target.value;
  this.setState(nextState);
}
```

we are using `Object.assign` here to create a new object (as a best practice you should never mutate the `this.state` directly)

the new `generateTableData()` function is simply iterating over the `this.state.ids` and calling `createRow`:

```
generateTableData() {
  let res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ids.length; i++) {
    let id = this.state.ids[i];
    let item = this.state.items[id];
    res.push(this.createRow(item));
  }
  return res;
}
```

as you can see, the new structure in `this.state` make it easy to lookup for items/ids

now, the last major change is on `createRow`, where we don't need to use an array anymore:

```
createRow(data) {
  return (
    <tr key={data.id}>
      <td>{data.deposit_name}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          id={data.id}
          type="text"
          value={data.amount}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

with that, we have a full working demo on:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-dynamic-input-datatable-2zygh

full code here:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export class Datatable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let tableData = this.props.snapshotData.data.deposits;
    let invenstments = tableData.Investment;
    let liquid = tableData.Liquid;
    let savings = tableData.Savings;
    let merged = [].concat(invenstments).concat(liquid).concat(savings);
    let state = {
      items: {},
      ids: [],
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
      state.items[merged[i].id] = merged[i];
      state.ids.push(merged[i].id);
    }

    this.state = state;

    this.generateHeader = this.generateHeader.bind(this);
    this.generateTableData = this.generateTableData.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let nextState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    nextState.items[event.target.id].amount = event.target.value;
    this.setState(nextState);
  }

  generateTableData() {
    let res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ids.length; i++) {
      let id = this.state.ids[i];
      let item = this.state.items[id];
      res.push(this.createRow(item));
    }
    return res;
  }

  generateHeader() {
    const columnHeader = ['Deposit name', 'Amount'];
    let res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < columnHeader.length; i++) {
      res.push(<th key={columnHeader[i]}>{columnHeader[i]}</th>);
    }
    return res;
  }

  createRow(data) {
    return (
      <tr key={data.id}>
        <td>{data.deposit_name}</td>
        <td>
          <input
            id={data.id}
            type="text"
            value={data.amount}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
              <h3 className="card-title">DataTable with default features</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <table
                id="example1"
                className="table table-bordered table-striped"
              >
                <thead>
                  <tr>{this.generateHeader()}</tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{this.generateTableData()}</tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>{this.generateHeader()}</tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you the onChange is now working but I am still not able to set the initial values on input boxes. For example, in the json given in my question, the initial values (visible as soon as page loads) of input boxes will be the amount value of json of each entry

Comment: @Yesha I see you updated your question, cool! I have updated the code too. The main difference is the `state` variable, now for the "default value" (or first value), we lookup `data[i].amount`. The example on CodeSandbox is also working based on this update

Comment: Thanks for the update. I can see the default values now but not able to delete these values. When I delete the whole value, the default value appears

Comment: @yesha  add this fix : `let state = this.state[`input-${data[i].id}`] !== undefined ? this.state[`input-${data[i].id}`] : data[i].amount;`

Comment: I updated codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-dynamic-input-datatable-forked-sersj?file=/src/Datatable.js

Comment: hey @Yesha, looks like a small refactor was needed :)... i updated my answer and the codesandbox on it... i moved your logic from `generateTableData` to the `constructuor` phase, helping setup the `this.state` with the correct data shape... as a rule of thumb, always try to shape your state/data structure before you run it in your component logic, it makes the rendering logic cleaner